# Import SVG : immediate crash

Tags: svg

I am trying to import a .svg from Inkscape 1.0 : it's a simple text that I have converted into a path.
Then I open Blender 2.83, try import .svg, and then I get an immediate crash from blender.
I have a "path" .svg, the module import .svg active. Any idea for why it goes wrong ?

Here is the link : https://1drv.ms/u/s!AlnEmWLfODePgX4Xj7Kb381bn9pT

Comment: can you share the svg?

Comment: As soon as I figure out how to post an attached file :S

Comment: Importing the linked SVG works well on my machine, in blender 2.83.

Comment: Hmmm....So sth is wrong with my config ?
Linux Mint 19.3 Tricia - 5.3.0-59-generic #53~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jun 4 14:58:26 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
Blender 2.83 - Flatpak

Comment: I can also import without any problem: https://filebin.net/b8kbb6hs3k83u75x here the blend file with SVG inside

Answer (score 0):

Solution : I removed the flatpak version and install again using snapd !